# Clojure idiomatic way to find duplicate values in a lazy collection (excluding some values from the check)

Tags: clojure

What would be the idiomatic way to find duplicate values in a lazy collection, excluding some values from the check?

Like:

```
(duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1) '(1)) ;; 1 is excluded from the check
false

(duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1) ()) ;; no exclusions
true
```

My requirement is that the code should be able to handle infinite lists. In other words, if duplicability can be pronounced by looking at the first `N` elements, the code shouldn't have to process the entire lazy collection.

My horribly messy try is:

```
(defn duplicates? [coll except]
  (let [_duplicates? (fn [coll except accum]
                         (let [item (first coll)]
                           (if (nil? item)
                             false
                             (if (some #{item} except)
                               (recur (rest coll) except accum)
                               (if (some #{item} accum)
                                 true
                                 (recur (rest coll) except (conj accum item)))))))]
    (_duplicates? coll except ())))
```

Comment: Sort and see if there are two identical numbers in succession

Comment: Wouldn't sorting take forever in an infinite collection? On the other hand you may be able to find duplicates by looking at the first `N` elements. I updated my post to make that point clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much better to reuse existing functions than to invent this by hand. This solution short-circuits as requested, and is obviously correct at first glance because it's just built out of existing primitives, which is a big win over the other suggested solutions: they are long and involved enough that they have to be inspected and carefully checked for errors (and those errors are easy to make, as shown by the fact that every solution proposed has gone through a round or two of fixes).

```
(defn duplicates? [coll except]
  (let [except (set except)
        filtered (remove #(contains? except %) coll)]
    (not= filtered (distinct filtered))))
```

This won't work with an infinite `except` list, since it uses sets, but clearly no solution can handle *both* arguments being infinite, so that's not really a drawback, just something to be aware of.

Comment: (distinct? '(0 0)) evals to true. you need (apply distinct ..)

Comment: you also need to escape the empty coll cause otherwise (duplicates? () #{}) breaks.

Comment: Man, I hate `distinct?`. I'm never reusing an existing function again.

Answer (score 3):

I would just do something simple like this:

```
(defn duplicates? [xs]
  (not= (count (distinct xs)) (count xs)))
```

As for removing duplicates, you could provide an optional second parameter, but that doesn't seem very idiomatic to me. Instead, I'd just use the built-in `remove` function, e.g.:

```
user=> (duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1))
true
user=> (duplicates? (remove #{1} '(1 2 3 4 1)))
false
```

In functional languages the "idomatic" solution usually consists of using a few existing higher-level functions to create your new functionality. In this case, we use `distinct` to remove duplicates, and `remove` (with a set as the filter function) to exclude elements from the check.

---

If you really want something lazy, here's a solution that will quit when you find a duplicate. It's based loosely off the implementation of `distinct`:

```
(defn duplicates? [xs]
  (loop [[x & xs :as coll] xs, seen #{}]
    (if (empty? coll) false
      (or (contains? seen x) (recur xs (conj seen x))))))
```

If you *really* want to included the "excluded items" set as a parameter as well (rather than just using `remove`), I'd make it optional by making the function multiple-arity:

```
(defn duplicates?
  ([xs exclude?] (duplicates? (remove exclude? xs)))
  ([xs] (loop [[x & xs :as coll] xs, seen #{}]
          (if (empty? coll) false
            (or (contains? seen x) (recur xs (conj seen x)))))))
```

This solution is also safe for collections containing `nil` and `false`:

```
user=> (duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1) #{1})
false
user=> (duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1) #{})
true
user=> (duplicates? [true false false])
true
```

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't `count` and `distinct` take forever on an infinite list? On the other hand you may be able to pronounce on the duplicability or not by not having to go through the entire list. I updated my post to make that point clear.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - It doesn't make sense to check for duplicates in an infinite collection. If there are no duplicates, it will never return. On the other hand, if you know it will return then you already know it has duplicates, so what's the point in checking?

Comment: depending on the context it could be possible by an end user (for instance) to abort the search if he decides it takes too long and he's satisfied that the duplicates, if such exist, are too far away from the head of the collection.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - Again, doesn't really make sense. If they only want to look at the first N elements then they can call `(duplicates? (take N coll))` instead of doing a messy abort. What *would* be inefficient about this is that it forces the generation of an entire lazy sequence. For example, if each element takes 10 seconds to generate, and you could get away with just checking the first 2, this probably wouldn't be the best solution.

Comment: or to put it another way, I would like the function to take forever only if has to take forever.

Comment: you may have a point on the possible use case of the function - still your solution would go through 10^9 items if given the list `(concat '(0) (range 10^9))`

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - You're right. I've updated my answer with a `nil`/`false`-safe solution that is still very succinct.

Comment: the update looks great but I can't accept it as it stands since it's not able to exclude values from the check.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - Sorry, I updated it again. I actually had the arity-overloaded solution for providing the `excluded` list in my first solution, then I removed it in favor of just calling `remove`. I've added it back in.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a set instead of a list for the exceptions and accumulator. Checks would then be like: is item in accumulator or exceptions? Probably a lot faster while still preserving laziness.

```
(defn duplicates? [coll except]
  (let [_duplicates?
        (fn [coll except accum]
          (if (seq coll)
            (let [item (first coll)]
              (if (contains? except item)
                (recur (rest coll) except accum)
                (if (contains? accum item)
                  true
                  (recur (rest coll) except (conj accum item)))))
              false))]
    (_duplicates? coll except #{})))

user=> (duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1) #{1})
false
user=> (duplicates? '(1 2 3 4 1) #{})
true
```

Note:

```
user=> (duplicates? (repeat 1) #{})
true
```

Comment: `(iterate identity 1)` ==> `(repeat 1)`

Comment: yeah I like the `if-let` and a set does make more sense.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - Note that due to the use of `if-let` (and how sets are being used), it fails on this input, saying there are no duplicates: `[nil nil nil]`. Same for `[false true false]`.